# How to import in Matlab a cellarray from a .txt file with columns as "text"?

Tags: matlab, import, cell-array

I have a .txt file which I want to import with code in Matlab as a cell. This .txt file has lines with different lengths and a combination of numbers and characters in them. Here is a sample of the file:

```html
*** After labeling ***
Elements: E11, E21, E31, E51, E61, E81, 
Connections: E11E61, E21E81, E31E61, E31E81, E51E81, 
*** After labeling ***
Elements: E11, E21, E31, E51, E61, E81, 
Connections: E11E61, E21E81, E31E51, E31E81, E61E81, 
*** After labeling ***
Elements: E11, E21, E31, E51, E61, E62, E81, 
Connections: E11E61, E21E81, E31E51, E31E62, E61E81, E62E81,
```

The results should look like this:

[image]

When I import the file using the Import Tool some columns are recognized as *text* and some as *numbers*. I have to manually change the type of the column from number to text for each of them:

[image].

More, I have to select ***cellarray*** instead of Column Vectors each time. The maximum length of the lines is known, 15.

I tried results = importfile('results') but it does not work. Does anybody have any suggestions for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some simple parsing routine that returns directly `elements` and `connections` as cell vectors.

NB: Parsing assumes text file is well formatted and is always elements, followed by connections.

```
function [elements, connections] = ReadElementsAndConnections(filename)
%[
    % For debug
    if (nargin < 1), filename = 'ElementsAndConnections.txt'; end

    % Read full file content
    text = fileread(filename);

    % Split on newline
    lines = strsplit(strtrim(text), '\n');

    % Parse
    elements = cell(0,1);
    connections = cell(0,1);
    isElementLine = true;
    lcount = length(lines);
    startElements = length('Elements:') + 1;
    startConnections = length('Connections:') + 1;
    for li = 1:lcount,

        % Skip empty lines or lines starting with '*'
        line = strtrim(lines{li});
        if (isempty(line) || (line(1) == '*')), continue; end

        % NOT VERY SAFE: Assuming we always have 'elements', followed by 'connections'
        if (isElementLine)
            elementsLine = lines{li}(startElements:end);
            elementsValues = strtrim(strsplit(elementsLine, ','));
            elements{end+1} = elementsValues(1:(end-1)); % Last value is empty.
            isElementLine = false;
        else
            connectionsLine = lines{li}(startConnections:end);
            connectionsValues = strtrim(strsplit(connectionsLine, ','));
            connections{end+1} = connectionsValues(1:(end-1)); % Last value is empty.
            isElementLine = true;
        end

    end
%]
end
```

You can then access `elements` and `connections` like this:

```
>> elements{1}

ans = 

    'E11'    'E21'    'E31'    'E51'    'E61'    'E81'

>> connections{3}

ans = 

    'E11E61'    'E21E81'    'E31E51'    'E31E62'    'E61E81'    'E62E81'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works perfectly. The assumption of having a well formatted file is correct. I have one more remark: since my complete code is requiring as input a cell where 'E11' and 'E21' are on different columns, I will have to build that from your results. I am working on it. :)